# NSLOOKUP fails while ping -a and Resolve-DnsName -DnsOnly succeeds

Tags: dns, nslookup

I am trying to complete an `nslookup` for a number of hosts on an affiliated domain, but all nslookups fail.  The usual explanation is that the connection is due to NetBIOS however in this case `Resolve-DnsName -DnsOnly` should preclude that explanation. The same argument goes for `ping -a`.

So to explain.  I am VPN'd into a network "DCCorpNet" and wish to complete an nslookup against the enterprises domain "enterprise.com".  I know A records exist for the hosts I'm checking against so I expect `'nslookup SomeHost.enterprise.com'` to return an IP address. However there is no response, and weirdly, `'ping -a SomeHost.enterprise.com'` and `'Resolve-DnsName - DnsOnly SomeHost.enterprise.com'` work as expected.

So how can I troubleshoot this?  And, what more do I need to learn to learn what I need to update on the hosts DNS records for them to respond to `nslookup`?

(Things are set up so I expect DNS issues in the opposite direction but not as they are.)

Comment: What if you specify the domain server to use for nslookup? You can use google's dns servers or the internal dns server. For example: `nslookup -q=all example.com 8.8.8.8` where the last parameter is the dns server to use as a query server.

Comment: Yep, I was just coming back to update that I was able to locate the DNS server for enterprise.com and now notice I *am* getting back a non-authoritative answer with MyLocalCorpNet.com appended as a suffix.  So what looks to be happening is the VPN config causes my local configuration to append my companies domain as a suffix preventing nslookup from resolving the requested host.  What's still frustrating is I want to understand why the same issue does not apply to 'Resolve-DnsName -dnsonly HOSTNAME'.

Comment: That's why you can specify another dns server. That'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I mean to say that even specifying the correct dns server I cannot resolve the hostname.  This appears to be due to a configuration somewhere appending '.MyLocalCorpNet.com' to any requests to 'HOST.enterprise.com' even with the correct dns server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently something causes the wrong dns server to respond.

You can add a dns server as parameter for NSLookup to use the correct one.

For example:

```
nslookup -q=all example.com 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Accepting your answer because it is relevant.  I still would like to understand the corp difference between nslookup -q=all hostname DnsServer and Resolve-DnsName -DnsOnly hostname if anyone has documentation on the steps each takes to append suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

The full answer is that nslookup does devolution.  It isn't enough to simply point at the correct authoritative name server.  You also need to include a '.' at the end of your hostname to suppress devolution.

Therefore, `nslookup -q=all host.enterprise.com DnsServer.enterprise.com` becomes `nslookup -q=all host.enterprise.com. DnsServer.enterprise.com`.

And there we go.